# Sending db QuerySelectField to Flask over AJAX with postgresql

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, wtforms

I am trying to implement AJAX in my forms but I'm not able to submit optional QuerySelectField data to the database.

The field itself is populated with values from another table, it should be optional and hidden for users with lower access level (should ne NULL in such case). If selected, it should insert value of id column corresponding to the selected entry.

The problem is that AJAX seems to completely ignore it and always submits it as NULL.

I am completely new to this, tried searching for possible solution but couldn't find anything.

my forms.py:

```
class DodajAdmin(FlaskForm):
name = StringField(_l('Imię'), validators=[DataRequired()])
surname = StringField(_l('Nazwisko'), validators=[DataRequired()])
email = StringField(_l('Email'), validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
phone = StringField(('Nr telefonu'), validators=[DataRequired(), 
Length(min=8, max=12, message='Nieprawidłowy nr telefonu')]) 

PESEL = StringField(('PESEL'), validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=11, max=11, message='Nieprawidłowy PESEL')])

pkk = StringField(('Numer PKK'), validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=20, max=20, message='PKK musi składać się z dokładnie 20 znaków')])

res_city = StringField(('Miasto zamieszkania'), validators=[DataRequired()])
res_address = StringField(('Ulica i nr domu/mieszkania'), validators=[DataRequired()])
notes = StringField(('Uwagi'))
submit = SubmitField(_l('Dodaj kursanta'))

def validate_pkk(self, pkk):
    kursant = Kursant.query.filter_by(PKK=pkk.data).first()
    if kursant is not None:
        raise ValidationError(_('Kursant o podanym numerze PKK już istnieje!'))

def validate_email(self, email):
    kursant = Kursant.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
    if kursant is not None:
        raise ValidationError(_('Kursant o podanym adresie email już istnieje!'))

def validate_pesel(self, PESEL):
    kursant = Kursant.query.filter_by(PESEL=PESEL.data).first()
    if kursant is not None:
        raise ValidationError(_('Kursant o podanym numerze PESEL już istnieje!'))

    def instructors():
        return User.query.all()

    def getformclass():
        formclass = DodajAdmin
        if current_user.access_level > 1 :
            setattr(formclass, "instructor", QuerySelectField('Instruktor prowadzący', query_factory=instructors, blank_text='Brak (jeszcze nie wybrano)', allow_blank=True))
        return formclass
```

routes.py

```
@bp.route('/students/add/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def dodaj_kursanta():

form_class = getformclass()
form = form_class()
access_level = User.query.filter(User.id == current_user.id)
icon = 'fas fa-user-plus'

if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.validate():
        if current_user.access_level > 1:
            kursant = Kursant(name=form.name.data, surname=form.surname.data, email=form.email.data, PKK=form.pkk.data, \
                PESEL=form.PESEL.data, phone=form.phone.data, res_city=form.res_city.data, res_address=form.res_address.data, instruktor=form.instructor.data, notes=form.notes.data, added_by=current_user.id)

        kursant = Kursant(name=form.name.data, surname=form.surname.data, email=form.email.data, PKK=form.pkk.data, \
                PESEL=form.PESEL.data, phone=form.phone.data, res_city=form.res_city.data, res_address=form.res_address.data, added_by=current_user.id)   
        db.session.add(kursant)
        db.session.commit()
        return '<div id="success-message" class="alert alert-success">Pomyślnie dodano kursanta.</div>'
        
    return jsonify(form.errors), 400     
return render_template('pages/dodaj-kursanta.html', title='Dodaj kursanta', form=form, icon=icon)
```

template

```
              <form id="form" method="POST">
              {{ form.csrf_token }}
              <div class="text-danger my-2" id="csrf_token-error">
              </div>
          <div class="form-group">   
          {{ form.name(class="form-control", placeholder="Imię") }}
          <div id="name-error" class="invalid-feedback"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">   
          {{ form.surname(class="form-control", placeholder="Nazwisko") }}
          <div id="surname-error" class="invalid-feedback"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">   
          {{ form.email(class="form-control", placeholder="Adres email") }}
          <div id="email-error" class="invalid-feedback"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group"> 
          {{ form.phone(class="form-control", type="number", placeholder="Telefon") }}
          <div id="phone-error" class="invalid-feedback"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">   
          {{ form.PESEL(class="form-control", type="number", placeholder="PESEL") }}
          <div id="pesel-error" class="invalid-feedback"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group"> 
          {{ form.pkk(class="form-control", placeholder="PKK") }}
          <div id="pkk-error" class="invalid-feedback"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group"> 
          {{ form.res_city(class="form-control", placeholder="Miasto") }}
          <div id="res_city-error" class="invalid-feedback"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group"> 
          {{ form.res_address(class="form-control", placeholder="Ulica/Dom") }}
          <div id="res_address-error" class="invalid-feedback"></div>
          </div>
          {% if current_user.access_level > 1 %}
          <div class="form-group"> 
          <label class="my-1 me-2">Instruktor prowadzący</label>
              {{ form.instructor(class="form-control") }}
          </div>
          {% endif %}
          <div class="form-group"> 
            {{ form.submit(class="btn-lg btn-primary", style="width: 100%") }}
          </div>
        </form>

<script>
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const successMessage = document.getElementById('success-message');
const fields = {
  csrf_token: {
      input: document.getElementById('csrf_token'),
      error: document.getElementById('csrf_token-error')  
  },
  name: {
      input: document.getElementById('name'),
      error: document.getElementById('name-error')
  },
  surname: {
      input: document.getElementById('surname'),
      error: document.getElementById('surname-error')
  },
  email: {
      input: document.getElementById('email'),
      error: document.getElementById('email-error')
  },
  phone: {
      input: document.getElementById('phone'),
      error: document.getElementById('phone-error')
  },
  PESEL: {
      input: document.getElementById('PESEL'),
      error: document.getElementById('pesel-error')
  },
  pkk: {
      input: document.getElementById('pkk'),
      error: document.getElementById('pkk-error')
  },
  res_city: {
      input: document.getElementById('res_city'),
      error: document.getElementById('res_city-error')
  },
  res_address: {
      input: document.getElementById('res_address'),
      error: document.getElementById('res_address-error')
  },
  instructor: {
      input: document.getElementById('instructor'),
      error: document.getElementById('instructor-error')
  }
  }
  form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const response = await fetch('/students/add/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
          csrf_token: fields.csrf_token.input.value,
          name: fields.name.input.value,
          surname: fields.surname.input.value,
          email: fields.email.input.value,
          phone: fields.phone.input.value,
          PESEL: fields.PESEL.input.value,
          pkk: fields.pkk.input.value,
          res_city: fields.res_city.input.value,
          res_address: fields.res_address.input.value,
          instructor: fields.instructor.input.value
      })
  });
  if (response.ok) {
      successMessage.innerHTML = await response.text();
      form.style.display = 'none';
      successMessage.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
      const errors = await response.json();
      Object.keys(errors).forEach((key) => {
        fields[key].input.classList.add('is-invalid');
        fields[key].error.innerHTML = errors[key][0];
      });
  }
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've managed to resolve the issue although I'm not certain why it behaved like described in the first place.

Turns out that moving second occurrence of variable 'kursant' in routes.py into else condition (see below) caused the form to pass all information correctly. For some reason it was attempting to insert the data twice within a single db session.

updated routes.py

```
@bp.route('/students/add/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def dodaj_kursanta():

form_class = getformclass()
form = form_class()
access_level = User.query.filter(User.id == current_user.id)
icon = 'fas fa-user-plus'

if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.validate():
        if current_user.access_level > 1:
            kursant = Kursant(name=form.name.data, surname=form.surname.data, email=form.email.data, PKK=form.pkk.data, \
                PESEL=form.PESEL.data, phone=form.phone.data, res_city=form.res_city.data, res_address=form.res_address.data, instruktor=form.instructor.data, notes=form.notes.data, added_by=current_user.id)
        else:
            kursant = Kursant(name=form.name.data, surname=form.surname.data, email=form.email.data, PKK=form.pkk.data, \
                PESEL=form.PESEL.data, phone=form.phone.data, res_city=form.res_city.data, res_address=form.res_address.data, added_by=current_user.id)   
        db.session.add(kursant)
        db.session.commit()
        return '<div id="success-message" class="alert alert-success">Pomyślnie dodano kursanta.</div>'
        
    return jsonify(form.errors), 400     
return render_template('pages/dodaj-kursanta.html', title='Dodaj kursanta', form=form, icon=icon)
```